# search a repeated structure with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of the structure:

```
A_1: text
a lot more text

A_2: some text
a lot more other text
```

Now I want to extract the descriptive title (A_1) and the following text. Something like 
[("A_1", "text\na lot more text"),("A_2", "some text\na lot more other text")]

My expression I use is

```
(A_\d+):([.\s]+)
```

But I get only [('A_1', ' '), ('A_2', ' ')].

Has someone an idea for me?

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to limit the match to another occurence of the searched start indicator.

```
(?s)A_\d+:.*?(?=\s*A_\d+:|$)
```

- `(?s)` dotall [flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) to make dot also match newlines
- `A_\d+:` your start indicator
- `.*?` match as few as possible (lazy dot)
- `(?=\s*A_\d+:|$)` until start pattern with optional spaces ahead or `$` end

[See demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aO2tR3/1) (Python code generator)

Comment: Just FYI: Python code generator is the buggiest (it seems to me) option at regex101.com. I'd suggest checking if the pattern/code yields exactly the same results in real code environment (say, [ideone.com](http://ideone.com)). This regex should work well anyway if declared with a raw string literal (i.e. `r"<PATTERN>"`).

Answer (score 1):

Your `[.\s]+` matches one or more literal dots (since `.` inside a character class loses its special meaning) and whitespaces. I think you meant to use `.` with a `re.DOTALL` flag. However, you can use something different, a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) (there are other ways, too).

You can use

```
(?s)(A_\d+):\s*((?:(?!A_\d).)+)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cK9zM6/1)

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/HrDJ1L):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(A_\d+):\s*((?:(?!A_\d).)+)', re.DOTALL)
test_str = "A_1: text\na lot more text\n\nA_2: some text\na lot more other text"
print(p.findall(test_str))
```

The `(?:(?!A_\d).)+` tempered greedy token will match any text up to the first `A_`+`digit` pattern.